# Alternative method for calculating mean for a 4D matrice

Tags: matlab

I need some advice on some AAM e.g. coding that I trying to understand. The result were unable to complete since an error occur that said that the Matlab is out of memory:

> Error using zeros
> Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

In the coding that causes the error was:

```
Error in AAM_MakeSearchModel2D (line 6)
drdp=zeros(size(ShapeAppearanceData.Evectors,2)+4,6,length(TrainingData),length(AppearanceData.g_mean));
```

the actual data in the drpd are:

```
drdp=zeros(13,6,10,468249);
```

Since the 4th array is large, it's understandable that the Matlab that I was using which is 32bit is out of memory. The output that the code will produce is a 2d. Here is the code that will later use the drpd:

```
drdpt=squeeze(mean(mean(drdp,3),2));
R=pinv(drdpt)';
```

The question that i want to ask is, is it possible to split the 4D matrices into smaller ones (e.g. 2D or 3D) and do normal addition and division (to get mean). If yes, how would one do it?

## edited 17/12/2013

I cannot used sparse since the 4D drpd is an initialization for obtaining another whole calculation that stored all weighted errors of model versus real into the drpd. I copy the part of the AAM function that calculate this drpd:

```
function R=AAM_MakeSearchModel2D(ShapeAppearanceData,ShapeData,AppearanceData,TrainingData,options)


% Structure which will contain all weighted errors of model versus real
% intensities, by several offsets of the parameters
drdp=zeros(size(ShapeAppearanceData.Evectors,2)+4,6,length(TrainingData),length(AppearanceData.g_mean));

% We use the trainingdata images, to train the model. Because we want
% the background information to be included

% Loop through all training images
for i=1:length(TrainingData);
    % Loop through all model parameters, bot the PCA parameters as pose
    % parameters
    for j = 1:size(ShapeAppearanceData.Evectors,2)+4
        if(j<=size(ShapeAppearanceData.Evectors,2))
            % Model parameters, offsets
            de = [-0.5 -0.3 -0.1 0.1 0.3 0.5];
           
            % First we calculate the real ShapeAppearance parameters of the
            % training data set
            c = ShapeAppearanceData.Evectors'*(ShapeAppearanceData.b(:,i) -ShapeAppearanceData.b_mean);
            
            % Standard deviation form the eigenvalue
            c_std = sqrt(ShapeAppearanceData.Evalues(j));
            for k=1:length(de)
                % Offset the ShapeAppearance parameters with a certain
                % value times the std of the eigenvector
                c_offset=c;
                c_offset(j)=c_offset(j)+c_std *de(k);
            
                % Transform back from  ShapeAppearance parameters to Shape parameters  
                b_offset = ShapeAppearanceData.b_mean + ShapeAppearanceData.Evectors*c_offset;
                b1_offset = b_offset(1:(length(ShapeAppearanceData.Ws)));
                b1_offset= inv(ShapeAppearanceData.Ws)*b1_offset;
                x = ShapeData.x_mean + ShapeData.Evectors*b1_offset;
                pos(:,1)=x(1:end/2); 
                pos(:,2)=x(end/2+1:end);


                
                % Transform the Shape back to real image coordinates
                pos=AAM_align_data_inverse2D(pos,TrainingData(i).tform);
                
                % Get the intensities in the real image. Use those
                % intensities to get ShapeAppearance parameters, which
                % are then used to get model intensities
                [g, g_offset]=RealAndModel(TrainingData,i,pos, AppearanceData,ShapeAppearanceData,options,ShapeData);

                % A weighted sum of difference between model an real
                % intensities gives the "intensity / offset" ratio
                w = exp ((-de(k)^2) / (2*c_std^2))/de(k);
                drdp(j,k,i,:)=(g-g_offset)*w;
            end
        else
            % Pose parameters offsets
            j2=j-size(ShapeAppearanceData.Evectors,2);
            switch(j2)
                case 1 % Translation x
                    de = [-2 -1.2 -0.4 0.4 1.2 2]/2;
                case 2 % Translation y
                    de = [-2 -1.2 -0.4 0.4 1.2 2]/2;
                case 3 % Scaling & Rotation Sx
                    de = [-0.2 -.12 -0.04 0.04 0.12 0.2]/2;
                case 4 % Scaling & Rotation Sy
                    de = [-0.2 -.12 -0.04 0.04 0.12 0.2]/2;
            end
            
            for k=1:length(de)
                tform=TrainingData(i).tform;
                switch(j2)
                    case 1 % Translation x
                        tform.offsetv(1)=tform.offsetv(1)+de(k);
                    case 2 % Translation y
                        tform.offsetv(2)=tform.offsetv(2)+de(k);
                    case 3 % Scaling & Rotation Sx
                        tform.offsetsx=tform.offsetsx+de(k);
                    case 4 % Scaling & Rotation Sy
                        tform.offsetsy=tform.offsetsy+de(k);
                end
                
                % From Shape tot real image coordinates, with a certain
                % pose offset
                pos=AAM_align_data_inverse2D(TrainingData(i).CVertices,  tform);
                
                % Get the intensities in the real image. Use those
                % intensities to get ShapeAppearance parameters, which
                % are then used to get model intensities
                [g, g_offset]=RealAndModel(TrainingData,i,pos, AppearanceData,ShapeAppearanceData,options,ShapeData);
             
                % A weighted sum of difference between model an real
                % intensities gives the "intensity / offset" ratio
                w =exp ((-de(k)^2) / (2*2^2))/de(k);
                drdp(j,k,i,:)=(g-g_offset)*w;
            end
        end
    end
end

% Combine the data to the intensity/parameter matrix, 
% using a pseudo inverse
% for i=1:length(TrainingData);
%     drdpt=squeeze(mean(drdp(:,:,i,:),2));
%     R(:,:,i) = (drdpt * drdpt')\drdpt;
% end
% % Combine the data intensity/parameter matrix of all training datasets.
% %
% % In case of only a few images, it will be better to use a weighted mean
% % instead of the normal mean, depending on the probability of the trainingset
% R=mean(R,3);    

drdpt=squeeze(mean(mean(drdp,3),2));
R=pinv(drdpt)';
%R = (drdpt * drdpt')\drdpt;
```

As you can see in the final code of the function, the 4D drpd is then squeeze and then calculate again to become a 2D matrices store in R. Because of 'Out of Memory' problem, the function cannot initialize the drpd because it used to much space (the drdp=zeros(13,6,10,**468249**)). Can I stored the data in a 2D or 3D form (split the drpd part) and then do simple addition and division to get the mean and then finally get the 'R'?

Thank you, and sorry for the long question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to use some sparse representation if many elements of`drdp`remain zero.
Matlab's`sparse`command only creates 2D matrices though so something like this might work?

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/167669

Once you get that to work you can worry about computing means --
apart from requiring a little bookkeeping that should be doable.